# multiple regression using rank?

Tags: multiple-regression, spearman-rho

I like how Spearman's correlation compares rank between two variables, since it puts less weight on my outliers but doesn't completely exclude them.  Is there an equivalent procedure using ranks that I can use for multiple regression?

I tried to simply rank each variable from low to high, and then perform regression using the "ranks", but the resulting model has a very low R2.

Comment: Are you 100% looking for multiple rank regression, or would you be happy with multiple regression that is outlier resistant? This is called "robust regression" and comes in many flavors.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading about robust regression and it looks like it will accomplish what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[Ordinal regression](https://www.fharrell.com/post/rpo/) is based on the rank-ordering of the outcome observations, without requiring any assumptions about things like error distributions. The idea is that the linear predictor is related to a shift in the *distribution* of ranked outcomes, with different types of ordinal models making different assumptions about the form of the shift. In practice, the regression models can be fairly insensitive to violations of those assumptions. Ordinal regression thus allows for many types of data that might violate the usual assumptions of ordinary multiple linear regression, even when robust methods are used to account for heteroscedasticity or outliers.